# AWS Amplify, init failed

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I'm trying to integrate AWS Amplify to my flutter project but having this issue while trying to run the **amplify init** command

```
init failed
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The 'request' argument must be string. Received type undefined
    at Object.onSuccess (/Users/osx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/init-steps/s9-onSuccess.ts:26:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/Users/osx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/commands/init.ts:24:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/Users/osx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/index.ts:181:5)
    at executePluginModuleCommand (/Users/osx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:161:3)
    at Object.executeCommand (/Users/osx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:26:5)
```

Comment: Need more info here - what version of amplify cli are you using?

Comment: Hey @RanvirMohanlal, I'm using the latest one, now it's OK, I solved the issue.

Comment: @Slimm I'm experiencing the same issue, could you share how you solved it please? Thanks!